# Data comparison on minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the following query.

```sql
select count(*), TRUNC(creation_date, 'MI')
from "AUDIT"
where MODULE_NAME = 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN'
and CREATION_DATE > TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('06/07/2022 05:40 +02:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZH:TZM')
and CREATION_DATE < TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('06/07/2022 06:20 +02:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI TZH:TZM')
group by TRUNC(creation_date, 'MI')
order by TRUNC(creation_date, 'MI') asc
```

Obtaining the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNc1d.jpg)

What I would like to achieve is to check when there are no values ​​in the counts. For example from 05:50:00 to 06:15:00 there are no counts and I would like to view the data. This calculation should be done from 00:00 to 23:59 on the same day minute by minute.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the times when there was no data by using a row-generator to generate all the minutes and then joining to that:

```sql
SELECT count(a.module_name),
       t.time AS creation_date
FROM   ( SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:40:00 +02:00'
                 + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AS time
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY 
                TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:40:00 +02:00'
                 + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
                 < TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:20:00 +02:00'
       ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "AUDIT" a
       ON     t.time <= a.creation_date
          AND a.creation_date < t.time + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
          AND a.MODULE_NAME = 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN'
GROUP BY t.time
ORDER BY t.time asc
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "AUDIT" (module_name, creation_date) AS
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:41:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 35 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:42:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 35 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:43:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 43 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:44:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 38 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:45:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 32 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:46:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 26 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:47:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 42 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:48:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 40 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:49:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 37 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:50:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:15:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:16:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 68 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:17:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 56 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:18:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 46 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN', TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:19:00 +02:00' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 45;
```

Outputs:

> | COUNT(A.MODULE_NAME) | CREATION_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.40.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 35 | 06-JUL-22 05.41.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 35 | 06-JUL-22 05.42.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 43 | 06-JUL-22 05.43.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 38 | 06-JUL-22 05.44.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 32 | 06-JUL-22 05.45.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 26 | 06-JUL-22 05.46.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 42 | 06-JUL-22 05.47.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 40 | 06-JUL-22 05.48.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 37 | 06-JUL-22 05.49.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 14 | 06-JUL-22 05.50.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.51.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.52.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.53.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.54.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.55.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.56.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.57.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.58.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 05.59.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.00.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.01.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.02.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.03.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.04.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.05.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.06.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.07.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.08.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.09.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.10.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.11.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.12.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.13.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 0 | 06-JUL-22 06.14.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 50 | 06-JUL-22 06.15.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 68 | 06-JUL-22 06.16.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 56 | 06-JUL-22 06.17.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 46 | 06-JUL-22 06.18.00.000000000 +02:00 |
> | 45 | 06-JUL-22 06.19.00.000000000 +02:00 |

---

If you just want the times when there is no data then use a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT t.time AS creation_date
FROM   ( SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:40:00 +02:00'
                 + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AS time
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY 
                TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:40:00 +02:00'
                 + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
                 < TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:20:00 +02:00'
       ) t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN "AUDIT" a
       ON     t.time <= a.creation_date
          AND a.creation_date < t.time + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
          AND a.MODULE_NAME = 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN'
GROUP BY t.time
HAVING COUNT(a.module_name) = 0
ORDER BY t.time asc
```

Or, using `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
WITH times (time) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:40:00 +02:00'
           + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY 
         TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 05:40:00 +02:00'
           + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
           < TIMESTAMP '2022-07-06 06:20:00 +02:00'
)
SELECT time
FROM   times t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM   "AUDIT" a
         WHERE  t.time <= a.creation_date
         AND    a.creation_date < t.time + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
         AND    a.MODULE_NAME = 'PERSONAL_PLUGIN'
       )
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1cb8cbd3fd12140599212b1dde54024a)*

Comment: Thanks again! the query works great! it was what I needed. But running it with timestamps from 00:00 to 23:59 of the same day (the data is a lot) goes over 30 minutes (oracle rack 19c), even setting it to 5 minutes and not to 1. Can you recommend a solution to speed up / optimize the query?

Comment: @Lucavox Added a version of the query to get the times with no entries that uses `NOT EXISTS`.